# Finding all non-negative integers that add up to a particular value or less, with number of integers changing

Tags: python, function, nested-loops

I am working in Python. I want to make a function that takes two values: `maxSum` and `n`. The output should be all the `n`-tuples of non-negative integers that add up to `maxSum` or less. For example, if `maxSum` is 2 and `n` is three, the output should be:

`[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0]]`

For any given value of `n`, I can do it, just by going through `n` for-loops. For example, if `n` is 3, I can simply do:

```
result = []

for i in range(maxSum + 1):
    for j in range(maxSum + 1 - i):
        for k in range(maxSum + 1 - i - j):
            tuple = [i, j, k]
            result.insert(len(result), tuple)
return result
```

But in the above example, I have typed the three for-loops by hand. That is not what I want. I want to be able to make a function that works for any `n`, that is, a function `tupleGenerator(maxSum, n)` that generates all such n-tuples. The problem is, I am unable to change the number of for-loops in the function based on the input `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry don't have enough rep yet to comment, but here's a solution from math stackexchange

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410399/how-to-find-all-the-n-tuples-with-nonnegative-integers-that-add-up-to-a-fixed-in

In particular Ocean Wong's answer, which includes a recursive Python solution (last answer on the page).

EDIT: slightly revised answer to include code as OP requested.

```
def stars_and_bars(num_objects_remaining, num_bins_remaining, filled_bins=()):
    """
    The Stars and Bars (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem can be thought of as
    1. Putting m-1 bars ("|") in amongst a row of n stars
    OR
    2. Putting n balls into m bins.

    This program lists all the possible combinations by doing so.
    """
    if num_bins_remaining > 1:
        # case 1: more than one bins left
        novel_arrangement = []  # receptacle to contain newly generated arrangements.
        for num_distributed_to_the_next_bin in range(0, num_objects_remaining + 1):
            # try putting in anything between 0 to num_objects_remaining of objects into the next bin.
            novel_arrangement.extend(
                stars_and_bars(
                    num_objects_remaining - num_distributed_to_the_next_bin,
                    num_bins_remaining - 1,
                    filled_bins=filled_bins + (num_distributed_to_the_next_bin,),
                )
                # one or multiple tuple enclosed in a list
            )
        return novel_arrangement
    else:
        # case 2: reached last bin. terminate recursion.
        # return a single tuple enclosed in a list.
        return [
            filled_bins + (num_objects_remaining,),
        ]

result = []
n = 3
for i in range(maxSum + 1):
    result.extend(stars_and_bars(i, n))
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks! The code there works only for a specific value of Sum. But of course, using a for loop from 0 to maxSum worked. I have upvoted your answer. It would be helpful for future reference if you could also add the for loop thing in your answer, I can mark your answer accepted then ig. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Python provides the `itertools` module that you can leverage for this:

```py
maxSum, n = 2, 3
p1 = it.combinations_with_replacement(range(n), n)
p2 = filter( lambda m: sum(m) <= maxSum, p1 )
p3 = it.chain.from_iterable(it.permutations(p) for p in p2)
p4 = list(set(list(p3)))
sorted(p4)
```

This should be much easier on the memory consumption. You should print each step (for example `print(list(p1)))` to understand what each step is doing. That is easier to understand than anything that I will write in text here.